# почему не работает оператор else на vs code на языке php

Tags: php

```
<?php

$a = 3;

$str = "heloo";

if ($str == "heloo");
   
 echo "YES";

else "NO";

?>
```

// выводит это
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE), expecting end of file in C:\OpenServer\domains\my-php\index.php on line 6

Comment: скиньте код, информации недостаточно.

Comment: А почему вы не ставите `;` после каждого символа ?!

Answer (score 0):

попробуй так

```
$str = "блаблабла";

if($str === "блаблабла") {
  echo "yes";
} else {
  echo "no";
}
```

скобки очень важны...

Comment: спасибо большое вам!

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "heloo";
if ($str == "heloo"):
    echo "YES";
else:
    echo "NO";
endif;
```

Пример - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6b907860ad5b4a5f241a1e4e9619f94744224a46

Информация - https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php